# Best Firefox/Chrome Plugin to view source?

Tags: html, css, code-inspection

I find myself seeing things like buttons, inputs, header, ect. and wanting the code so I can reference off them and make my elementary designs look better. I always try to change it up a bit, I don't like stealing other peoples designs.

Viewing the page source from just the browser is very sloppy and usually hard to read. I tried using Firebug but I noticed one huge problem. It doesn't show all the CSS.

Example
Firebug will only show:

```css
box-shadow: 0 14px 10px -12px rgba(111,112,114,0.8);
```

When the full code is:

```css
box-shadow: 0 14px 10px -12px rgba(111,112,114,0.8);  
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 14px 10px -12px rgba(111,112,114,0.8);  
-moz-box-shadow: 0 14px 10px -12px rgba(111,112,114,0.8);
```

If leaves out the moz and webkit.

Comment: Firebug only shows `box-shadow` because that is the one which firefox is using. If you want the full source just use 'view source' :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can speak with experience in the Chrome Inspect tool, when debugging the page elements the browser automatically ignores and does not show the invalid properties or styles, but if you look at the actual page source code (or the css) your styles will be there.

I think that if Firebug does not show those styles it means Firefox is ignoring them, in this case you are using the `-moz-box-shadow` but Firefox uses `box-shadow` to render the element.

Answer (score 0):

download the latest version of any browser and you see absolutely all the css.

With Inspector in Chrome you can see even the different states like `:hover` `:active` and so on

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use the inspect element that's built in to Chrome? I use it every day of my life and love it.

I also use "stylebot" to show me some styles of websites, but I only use that to style websites (clientside) that I feel need a bit of fixing, like making buttons bigger, etc.